# How many processes would be created from fork() in this code?

Tags: c, multithreading, process, fork

This is a question from one of my tasks and I'm having some confusion with it.

> ```
> int main() 
> { 
>   printf("line\n");
>   pid_t pid = fork();
>   fork();
>   fork();
>   if(pid == 0)
>     fork();
>
>   fork();
>   printf("line\n");
>   return 0; 
> }
> ```
>
> How many processes would be created from the execution of the code?

From executing the code, it would generate 28 lines of output and just not sure how to find the amount of processes created in this statement.

Comment: Finally, it would produce 24 processes.So it would produce 25 lines I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As above, 24 leaves produce.So 24 processes produce finally.And before your first fork, "line" will be printed one time. After you `fork`, because of 24 processes, 24 "line" will be printed. So you will have 25 "line".

Comment: This is a great explanation :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**There will be a total of 24 processes. Here is how.**

After the first fork() there are two processes. In one of them `pid == 0`; in the other process `pid != 0`.

After second fork, there are 4 processes (half of them have `pid == 0`).

After third fork, there are 8 processes (and half of them have `pid == 0`).

The fourth fork statement is executed only by those processes where `pid == 0`. So 4 processes will execute fork (and turn into 8 processes). The other 4 processes will not execute fork and will remain 4. Alltogether we have 8+4=12 processes.

Finally, another fork turns our 12 processes into 24.

**How many threads would be created from the execution of the code?**

Now is the question of semantics. Do you say that processes are not threads, and so **0** threads are created? Do you say that out of 24 processes, the first one is the original process and not created by this code, so a total of 23 processes are created? This is a question of semantics, not of software, so we can't help you with this.

**Number of lines printed**

The first printf is executed by the original process only (since it has not forked yet). The second printf is executed by all 24 processes (just before each process terminates). So a total of 25 lines is printed.